# Looking for some clarification on why my if statement isn't working

Tags: javascript

I am attempting a challenge on codewars as follows:

**Story**

YouTube had a like and a dislike button, which allowed users to express their opinions about particular content. It was set up in such a way that you cannot like and dislike a video at the same time.

There are two other interesting rules to be noted about the interface: Pressing a button, which is already active, will undo your press. If you press the like button after pressing the dislike button, the like button overwrites the previous "Dislike" state. The same is true for the other way round.

**Task**

Create a function that takes in a list of button inputs and returns the final state.

Examples

```
likeOrDislike([Dislike]) => Dislike
likeOrDislike([Like, Like]) => Nothing
likeOrDislike([Dislike, Like]) => Like
likeOrDislike([Like, Dislike, Dislike]) => Nothing
```

Notes

If no button is currently active, return Nothing.
If the list is empty, return Nothing

I was stuck trying mutliple different ways to solve it for a couple of hours before checking the solutions and found one very similar to mine, albeit with one difference.

My code is as follows:

```
function likeOrDislike(buttons) {
  let answer = 'Nothing';

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i] !== 'Nothing') {
      answer = buttons[i];
    }
  }

  return answer;
}
```

Working solution below:

```
function likeOrDislike(buttons) {
  let state = 'Nothing';

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i] === state) {
      state = 'Nothing';
    } else {
      state = buttons[i];
    }
  }

  return state;
}
```

So it's pretty much the same method used to solve it, however I don't understand why in the working solution, you have to declare the variable 'state' as 'Nothing' again when it's already been declared outside the loop.

I thought that I could just create one condition for if `buttons[i]` is not equal to 'Nothing' and then assumed it it would default to 'Nothing' in any other case since it was declared outside of the loop.

Comment: The declaration outside the loop is nothing but an initial state. As the loop is looping, the value of `state` will be overwritten. And in that case, when you find `Like,Like` or `Dislike,Dislike`, you have to set it back to `'Nothing'`.

Comment: Also, in your own code, you have `buttons[i] !== 'Nothing'`, that can never be false because button values are either `Like` or `Dislike`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging read it out loud on what it does.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi that is not correct.

Comment: Like, Like, Like !== LIke, Like

Comment: @epascarello Like... like like like

Comment: Thanks @GhassenLouhaichi. Yeah, that makes sense now I've had another look after a break and some and your explanation helped me understand it.

Comment: Also @epascarello ,yeah I'll keep that in mind. I guess visualing it on a notepad may help too, trying to follow an input from start to finish and seeing what happens at each stage.

Comment: Please give your question a more specific title. Most questions here are about code that doesn't work to solve their problem. The title should summarize the specific problem you're having that distinguishes it from other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'reduce' is perfect for this situation. If the same button is pressed twice, you get Nothing. Otherwise, the button pressed is the new state.

```js
const [Nothing, Like, Dislike] = ['Nothing', 'Like', 'Dislike']

function likeOrDislike(seq) {
  return seq.reduce((a,c) => a===c ? Nothing : c, Nothing)
}

console.log(likeOrDislike([Dislike])) // Dislike
console.log(likeOrDislike([Like, Like])) // Nothing
console.log(likeOrDislike([Dislike, Like])) // Like
console.log(likeOrDislike([Like, Dislike, Dislike])) // Nothing
```

Comment: I haven't learnt how to use reduce yet, but it seems fairly simple. Thanks for the answer and I'll research it tomorrow so I can understand what happened.